# Odd behavior of clip?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, clip

The following creates an unexpected clip path. Is it because of the
movement from the end of one arc to the start of the next? The circles turned out to be ellipses, which was also unexpected.

```
var canvas3=document.getElementById("drawing3"); 
var ct=canvas3.getContext("2d"); 

ct.beginPath();
ct.arc(50,80,30,0,Math.PI*2,false);
ct.arc(120,40,60,0,Math.PI*2,true);
ct.arc(180,40,30,0,Math.PI*2,true);
ct.arc(240,40,30,0,Math.PI*2,true);
ct.clip();

ct.fillStyle="yellow";
ct.fillRect(10,10,400,200);
ct.fillStyle="magenta";
ct.font = "40px sans-serif";
ct.fillText("what's this?",30,70);
```

By the way, does a clip area always have to start with beginPath()?

Answer (score 0):

**Why ellipses instead of arcs**

Although you don't include your CSS, canvas drawings become deformed when the canvas element is resized with CSS. The default size of html5 canvas is 300x150 so adjusting its size with CSS will stretch or squish subsequent drawings unless the CSS resizes the canvas exactly in proportion to its original 2:1 proporitions.

So, if you want to resize the canvas do the resizing by changing the element's size directly:

```
var canvas3=document.getElementById("drawing3"); 
canvas3.width=400;
canvas3.height=300;
```

**Why `beginPath` is useful (essential!)**

A `context.clip` always acts upon the last set of path commands and a set of path commands *should* be started with `context.beginPath`. So yes, a clip *should* always start with context.beginPath.

*Why is `beginPath` useful (always use it!):* If you issue multiple sets of path commands without starting each set with beginPath, then each new set will also execute all previous sets. Your path will just become one long drawing rather than having distinct drawings.

**Fixing the inter-connected circles**

`context.arc` is a canvas path drawing command.

Path commands will always connect (with a line) all drawings that occur between `context.beginPath` and `context.stroke or context.fill`.

But you can command the path to "pick up the pencil and move it to the next circle center" using `context.moveTo`. This will prevent your circles from becoming inter-connected.

```
// pick up the pencil and move it to the next arc's centerpoint
ct.moveTo(x,y);
// and draw the arc around the centerpoint
ct.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,false);
```

[image]

**Here's your code refactored to "pick up the pencil" between arcs:**

```js
var canvas3=document.getElementById("drawing3"); 
var ct=canvas3.getContext("2d"); 

ct.beginPath();
arcAtXY(50,80,30);
arcAtXY(120,40,60);
arcAtXY(180,40,30);
arcAtXY(240,40,30);
ct.clip();

ct.fillStyle="yellow";
ct.fillRect(10,10,400,200);
ct.fillStyle="magenta";
ct.font = "40px sans-serif";
ct.fillText("what's this?",30,70);

function arcAtXY(x,y,r){
    ct.moveTo(x,y);
    ct.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,false);
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="drawing3" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**An additional thought not directly related to your design**

If you want to **stroke** the circles instead of filling them, you would move to the next circle's perimeter rather than its centerpoint. Moving to the centerpoint would cause an automatic line to draw from the centerpoint to the perimeter.

```
function arcAtXY(x,y,r){
    ct.moveTo(x+r,y);
    ct.arc(x,y,r,0,Math.PI*2,false);
}
```